# unicode decoding error while converting byte list

Tags: python, list, decoding, opus

I am trying to decode a raw audio data using libopus. The data is continuous for 5 seconds which is a str type. I later convert the str into list and then into a byte list using the code-

```
bytelist = [x.decode('utf-8')for x in new_list]
```

However, I am receiving an error stating:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf9 in position 4: invalid start byte
```

Here is the byte list:

```
b'\x00Z\x15\x02\xf9\x15q\x9d1$\xd2\xde:\xb44\xaf\x8d_4\xbe\xe5\x02\x1f\x87\xe1\x84x\xb1\xcb\x13;XY+\x9b\xd8\xeb\xc1\nG\xe9\x1b\xba\x12\xe4\x9d\xaa4\xce\xa0r\xd5\xcf\x00\xa6\xaa2\x17nGw\xc3Sm\t\xe8\x1c\xc2\xb5&\xe8}++h\xa1\x1c\x1e\x9e)\xbb\x08\xa9\xd5\x960\x17\xb1\xb4\xa8*\x90x\xd8jK\x99:\xc7\xb7\x8d\xc2\xc0t\x80'
 b'\x01ZH\x81\x8c\x97jA\xfeb\xecg\xc2P\r9"\xe9\x8e\xaa-k\xef\xe6b2@\xdc\x1e\xb4\xe8\xd3\xbc4\xb4aU\xf1\xccG\xbb\xf0:>\x93p\xd0\x18`?\x9f\x1c\xa3\xf2\'\x8a\xf3\x07\xe7:\xe3\x1a\xc5XbG\xc0\x89\xfb)d\xba\xcf\x8b0\x03HmR\x9b;I\xff\xbcw!5\x93\x9b\xdb\x0e\x13fH\xde\xa5\x93\xb7\x8b\n}\x19\x0b\xd2\xd0\xd9\xa1j7s\xda\x84\x85\xe0%\xfb\x07\xa5U\x08\x84\xfdg:^\xd5\xb6\xe6\xdbV\xff\xff('
 b'\x02Z7\x03\x0e\xe77\x17\xe3\xff\x9d\xb3\xe5\xa3\xcd\x84X\xcb\x00~\x88\xc0T<\xa3\xe8\xd3\x02\xe8Cs\xef\x15\x10\x07\x9c\xd1\xea\x96\x94\xe7\x9d\x9cE\xf41~\xfb\xbfo\n\xa2\x15\xbb\x9ex\x910\x03\x0fw^U\\P\x1ey\x006W\xcb[\x1a{\xb9\xf8\xacO\xf7\xeb\xffo\x14;\xa0\xa9X\xe6{*\xac\xa9\x14\x96\xc4\xdaq\x80\x0eC^\xd4w\xe2?\xfd\xa2\x0fCk\xe8\xe3\x02\x0b3\xd3'
 b"\x03Z8\x03\x0e\xa5\x9b\xb3\x1bV\x84\xc5\xc3\x0c5\x06\xf0\x10\x9f\x00\x87N\xdd\xb9\x8e\xe3\x1e\xaenj\xb8>\xb76\x80ndwZ\xa11\x0c\n\xe1\xeaz'\x8d\x81E\xaf\x81\xb4\xf9\xb4\xfb3v\xd9\x02\xd4\xca\x11]J\x18\x93\x95\x01\xbc\xbb\xce\x8d\xd1#\x9cg\x19,& p\x12\x058\x86~A\xbb>p\xec/T9\xa0\xa6\x9eND\x81\x13\xe2\xa8z\xb3\x18|M \xb2\xd8\x94/\xdcr\x01\x82\x84"
 b'\x04Z8\x02\xd5a\xc0Y\xa6\xc3\t\x19t\x0f]\xd3q\x06\xfe\x91\x80\xd5\x92\xd5N\xf4f_\xd4\x05(DjcshX\xc9\x0c\xa9\xc3\x94!\xdbI\xe8\x84\x1b\xe6\x91~9dY@\x115\xba\x91\x02\xd5oL\x1d\xc4\xe1+\x9e~K\x88\xd8o\xc1m\x7f\xf3\xbfKN\xc1\n\xee/k\x93p\xfe\xfb\xb4\x8d\xa5\xfc\xb9\xdd1\x9b\xa4"\xc1\xed4\x1e\xa4\x8b\xc4\x95'
```

steps for initialization:

```
   await asyncio.wait_for(authenticate(ws, username, password, token, channel), WS_TIMEOUT_SEC)
    print(f"User {username} has been authenticated on {channel} channel")
    print("Wait for response")
    stream_id = 1 #Initialize some random value
    print("Receiving started")
    await asyncio.gather(stream_receive(ws))
    print("Receiving ended")
    print("")
    for i in range(0, len(new_list)):
        print(new_list[i], "\n")
    print("Data received successfully")
    await asyncio.wait_for(stream_stop(ws, stream_id), WS_TIMEOUT_SEC)
```

Small part of the code that generates the data:

```
async def stream_receive(ws):
    await ws.receive_str()
    async for msg in ws:
        print("msg:", ws) #prints:aiohttp.client_ws.ClientWebSocketResponse object at 0x7ff4469de5e0
        global new_list
        DATA = str(msg.data)
        print("data_ type: ",type(DATA))  # str type      
        print("data =", DATA) #produces the data with stream id + packet_id + audio data
        if msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.TEXT:
            data = json.loads(msg.data)
            if data["command"] == "on_stream_stop":
                print("Stream stopped")
                return False
        elif msg.type == aiohttp.WSMsgType.BINARY:
            audio_byte = msg.data[8:] #gives only the audio data
            print("type", type(audio_byte)) #bytes type
            print(audio_byte)
```

Is there any method to get over this issue.

Comment: Why are you trying to decode it into UTF-8 ? If it is "raw audio data", then it should definitely not be decoded as Unicode text ! Also, please provide a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because we don't know the types of the elements in `new_list`.

Comment: The type of element under new_list is mentioned (the bytearray in byte list). I forgot to highlight it. Thank you for the clarification on the UTF-8. However, do you know any way to decode it?

Comment: [`bytearray.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.decode) will "Return a string decoded from the given bytes", and in Python "strings" are considered to be valid Unicode text. WHich your audio data clearly is not. You should not be using this `decode` function. Instead, you should use a proper audio-decoding function, which one depends on how the audio got encoded in the first place. You may have to read `libopus` documentation or tutorials to know how to do it. But I don't have enough context to answer you, that's why I recommend a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: Sorry for the late response and than you for the advice. I have added some code that might be helpful as an example.